# mysql - count two columns in same query with specific variables

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database structured like:

table `transactions`:

```
id  paymentid clientid status
------------------------------
1   001       12345      0
2   002       11223      1
3   003       12345      4
4   004       12345      4
```

What is the most efficient way to run a query in mysql to give me the number of times a certain clientid had payments with the status of 4?

like:

```
select clientid, count(*) 
where status = 4
```

but only return the count of a specific clientid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just add a `WHERE` filter for `clientId` if you want to filter by a specific client. If not, then you can remove the `and clientid = 12345`:

```
select clientid, count(*) 
from transactions
where status = 4 
  and clientid = 12345
GROUP BY clientId;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a994a/3)

Comment: You don't need the where filter for the clientId. You do need the Group By clause for the clientId

Comment: @MarkS. If they want to filter by a specific client id you do. They stated _number of times a certain clientid_ which implies a where.